# React - How to remove external Source links from the production build

Tags: reactjs

I am building react app which is run in an environment that does not connect to the internet (run on an internel network which makes it can't access to the external services)

But some dependencies of app user services from external services. For example, in the build files, there is a link to google font API as following.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin);
```

If those links are directly used inside my app then it would be easy to download resource from the service and use downloaded content instead of the external link. But the problem is it used those external link in the dependencies.

So, Is there programmatic ways to resolve this which resolve these external links when we build the react app?

Thanks early for your advice.